# Python copy all lines before string in another text file

Tags: python, io, text-files, deque

I have stacked in my code, I want from this code to open file that already exists with huge text (inputt), read it and If line contains "***" then copy lines before it and paste in another file (outputt).

My inputt file for example looks like this:

```
This is the house

this is the flower

this is a tree

'***'

This is a car

this is an apple

this is the nature

'***'
```

So my goal is to copy all lines before "***" and paste it in another file. So it can be separated into two files. Here is my stacked code:

```
def transform(inputt, outputt):
    with open(inputt) as f, open(outputt, "w") as f1:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            if "***" in line:
                f.writelines(deque(f1, count))
            else:
                count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. Given your description and example input file, it sounds like you would want the following written to outputt:

```
This is the house

this is the flower

this is a tree
```

Is that correct? If so:

```
def transform(inputt, outputt):
    with open(inputt) as f, open(outputt, "w") as f1:
        f1.write(f.read().split("***")[0])
```

This code has a number of flaws, but without a better description it's hard to really know what you're after.

Edit:
Given the response in the comments:

```
def transform(inputt, outputt_base):
    with open(inputt, "r") as f:
        for count, block in enumerate(f.read().split("***")):
            outputt_name = outputt_base + "_{0}.txt".format(count)
            with open(outputt_name, "w") as f1:
                f1.write(block)
```

Given your example input file, this would write two output files:
(Assuming `outputt_base` is just the string `output`)

First file: `output_1.txt`

```
This is the house

this is the flower

this is a tree
```

and

Second file: `output_2.txt`

```
This is a car

this is an apple

this is the nature
```

Comment: That's right! Sorry for bad explanation. But I need for every that 'block'to put in different text file. Because there is a lot of more *** in text. So the for loop should start and after *** is found, put in first file, after starts loop again and writes second block in another file until there is no *** in text file. Could you understand this? Thank you!

Comment: That really works! Thank you, I wrote something like your edit by I have a lot of scripts because I am new to python. Thank you, you really helped me!